# When should I directly use EntryPoints.get instead of EntryPointsAccessor.from*?

Tags: dagger-hilt

In Dagger Hilt, we have @EntryPoint annotation to use.

As shared in https://dagger.dev/hilt/entry-points.html, we can get access the Entry points through

```
EntryPoints.get(applicationContext, MyClassInterface.class)
```

However, I also notice in https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-dagger-to-hilt#4, we use `EntryPointAccessors` instead as below.

```
EntryPointAccessors.fromApplication(applicationContext, RegistrationEntryPoint::class.java)
```

When should we use `EntryPoints.get` vs `EntryPointAccessors.from*`?

Comment: they resolve to the same usage, EntryPointAccessors are just more type safe

Answer (score 0):

As is written [here](https://dagger.dev/hilt/entry-points.html) in "Access an EntryPoint" section

> Additionally, the methods in `EntryPointAccessors` are more appropriate and type safe for retrieving entry points from the standard Android components.

If you use standard Android components you will use `EntryPointAccessors` else you can use `EntryPoints`